# How does the byte stream from VideoSink.OnSample look?

Tags: c#, silverlight, image, image-processing, webcam

In Silverlight, the [`VideoSink.OnSample`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.videosink.onsample%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method is used to get raw webcam data. The function signature is as follows:

```
protected abstract void OnSample(
    long sampleTimeInHundredNanoseconds,
    long frameDurationInHundredNanoseconds,
    byte[] sampleData
)
```

Documentation for `sampleData` says

> A byte stream that contains video data. The byte stream should be processed into samples according to the relevant video format information.

Going to the documentation of the [`VideoFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.videoformat%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class, one gets to the [`VideoFormat.PixelFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.videoformat.pixelformat%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property which can only have two possible values according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pixelformattype%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

> - **Unknown** - The format is unknown.
> - **Format32bppArgb** - The format uses 32 bits of color information per pixel and reports color information by using alpha, red, blue, and green channels.

I want to understand how the `sampleData` parameter for the [`VideoSink.OnSample`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.videosink.onsample%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method looks like. Is it simply an array of pixels like the following?

```
sampleData[0] = image[x = 0, y = 0].R;
sampleData[1] = image[x = 0, y = 0].G;
sampleData[2] = image[x = 0, y = 0].B;
sampleData[3] = image[x = 0, y = 0].A;
sampleData[4 to 7] = image[x = 0, y = 1];
sampleData[8 to 11] = image[x = 0, y = 2];
sampleData[4*Height-4 to 4*Height-1] = image[x = 0, y = Height];
sampleData[4*Height to 4*Height+3] = image[x = 1, y = 0];
// ...
```

If it is that easy: Is the ordering correct?

- R before G before B before A for each pixel
- All pixels of first column before all pixels of second column and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The byte stream looks as follows for the Format32bppArgb pixel format:

```
sampleData[0- 3] = image[x=0, y=0]
sampleData[4- 7] = image[x=1, y=0]
sampleData[8-11] = image[x=2, y=0]
      ...                ...
                   image[x=w, y=0]
                   image[x=0, y=1]
                         ...
                   image[x=w, y=h]
```

So, it is stored row by row.

For each pixel which is stored in bytes *i* to *i+3* the information comes as follows:

```
sampleData[i+0] = BLUE
sampleData[i+1] = GREEN
sampleData[i+2] = RED
sampleData[i+3] = ALPHA
```

All channels are stored as an integer in the range [0; 255] where 255 indicates the maximum intensity for the color channels and opaque for the alpha channel. So, besides the ordering it works like expected.